# Providing ToString() for my custom object

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a class with lots of, lots of, lots of properties.
In my programm i have to log heavily. Often I have to manually
build log strings like

```
string log = "Current state of object:" + "Property1" + myObj.Property1 + ...
```

1. I just thought what if override `ToString` and provide logging of whatever I need. It is considered goog practice?
2. How can I provide formatter control string? Say I want my ToString to operate in two modes
   one is complete ouput of all properties and another light version wheere only relevant properties are output

Something like MyObj.ToString("full") and MyObj.ToString("basic")

Comment: i override .ToString all the time for debugging. i dont see a problem with it.

Comment: ditto. Overriding ToString() gives much nicer "watch" windows in VS.

Comment: Posting this as a comment as the OP explicitly *didn't* mention the debugger, but logfiles, etc.: If you're only concerned about the debugger (watches) you might be better of using the DebuggerDisplayAttribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx). Additionally, too complicated ToString() operations might slow down the debugger, because they are (re)evaluated pretty often, or cause an exception and you see nothing at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding `ToString` is indeed good practice, so long as you provide good information.

As for having different types of `ToString` - this is possible, but then you will not be overriding `ToString`, but providing an overload (that any using class will need to know about).

I would implement the `lightweight` version as the override and create a `VerboseToString` function for the full set of properties.

If you have many such objects, you can create a `IVerboseString` interface with a `VerboseToString` method and implement it in your objects. This way you can simply use the interface reference in your logging.

Comment: Right so I override ToString if I want compatibility or i provide MyOwnOutput() if I want "features"

Comment: @Captain Comic - You can do both :)

Answer (score 1):

1. That's an excellent practice
2. You could, of course, parametrize the ToString method, but it would no longer mean an implicit conversion from object to string, so you can't write, say, `string x = myObject`; you will have to call ToString explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you overriding ToString but not creating a method that takes Enum as parameter and does what you want inside?

Comment: what does enums have to do with this??

Comment: @RPM1984 - better than voodoo magic constants I guess? But yeah I don't like it here either. The IVerbose interface has more reuse.

Comment: @RPM1984: OP stated that he needed 2 operations (full and basic). I wouldn't override ToString but write a new method for this since you can't override toString and add that Enum as a parameter.

Comment: Right, i misunderstood. My bad. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any particular problem associated with it, and myself I often appreciate it for spitting out info in unit tests or trace etc. but I'd take issue with your implementation for verbose and concise outputs - don't use voodoo strings or any kind of arbitrary input - I'd prefer it here id you either took an input argument `bool verbose` or you explicitly created a `ToStringVerbose()` method. It's also good practice IMHO for your overridden method to use `base.ToString()` as part of it's implementation.